# Gluon Mobile JavaFX show black screen on Running. with FXML file

Tags: android, javafx, fxml, gluon

So I was Facing the Issue for 3-4 days. Black screen on my android. and I got a problem why it was showing me the black screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<VBox alignment="TOP_CENTER" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="727.0" prefWidth="551.0" spacing="20.0" style="-fx-background-color: rgb(50,50,50);" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="org.crypto.views.LoginController">
   <children>
      <Label text="RYPTO" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font name="Eras Demi ITC" size="39.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <VBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="500.0" spacing="40.0">
         <children>
            <TextField fx:id="user_input" alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="350.0" promptText="username">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Gabriola" size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </TextField>
            <PasswordField fx:id="pass_input" alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="350.0" promptText="password">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Gabriola" size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </PasswordField>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#login" text="LOGIN">
               <font>
                  <Font size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </children>
</VBox>
```

it's because of this FXML file. I don't understand why? but When I remove this file it worked.
So What could be the reason behind this problem?

Please Help. and Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Anything in [logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat)? Do you have a stack trace? If you do then [edit] your question and post the entire stack trace (as text and not as an image).

Comment: I don't get error or anything. on client:build. it shows me in runtime. on android. I tried to build for desktop and that's worked too

Comment: I didn't use logcat. but I do trycatch while loading. the fxml and set if that failed just close the application. but the app doesn't closed either. just stay blacked screen.

Comment: Try removing the following from your FXML file, because it is not required: `xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171"` Also, did you create the controller class? According to your FXML file its name is `org.crypto.views.LoginController`

Comment: Yea I Made Controller class. and it worked fine.

Comment: You _do_ need to read the logcat, and find the stacktrace. If you post it, we can help. Otherwise it is a wild guess. Most certainly you are missing some class from config files. You can run `client:runagent` to get those config files on desktop, then build again for Android. All explained here: https://docs.gluonhq.com/#_the_gluon_client_plugin_for_maven

Comment: Well. I do stack trace in my own way. and the I found it says the error is in fxml 20 line. where are the fonts.  this one -> <font>
            <Font name="Eras Demi ITC" size="39.0" />
         </font>

Comment: so how I add the fonts.

Comment: <TextField fx:id="user_input" alignment="CENTER" promptText="username"/>
            <PasswordField fx:id="pass_input" alignment="CENTER" promptText="password"/>

Comment: Android Logs says The Error is in TextField Line